# wordpress error in server, but localhost work very well

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry, I could not found which error come from.
If i active woocommerce, theme will show error

There's a problem with your WordPress jQuery library. This can have several causes, including incompatible plugins.
The Mantra Settings page cannot function without jQuery. You need to fix this issue before you can configure Mantra.

but if i using Twenty Thirteen theme, there is no problem.

If i deactivate woocommerce, the theme mantra can be use without any error.

I have try to look for many information, could not found a solution.

One more, i have setup by using wamp localhost, there is no problem withw woocommerce and mantra together.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: when using mantra theme, it show error, There's a problem with your WordPress jQuery library. This can have several causes, including incompatible plugins. The Mantra Settings page cannot function without jQuery. You need to fix this issue before you can configure Mantra.

If using woocommerce, it just show blank page, and error 505.